# Uploading and displaying images in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I am buiding a website which will be having a form like this

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
         <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    
            <div class="col-12 text-center tm-submit-container">
                <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary tm-btn-submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
    </form>
```

here i need to upload a image in this page and show it in demo.php page(redirects when submitted)
demo.php

```
<body>
<p style="text-align: right;" id="time"></p>
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
    welcome
</h1>
</body>
```

can someone help me how to do it?i tried tutorials in w3 schools but that didnot work.

Comment: what you want??

Comment: i want to display the uploaded image in demo.php

Comment: you upload image in database & folder also??

Comment: only folder not database

Answer (score 1):

**View Page:-**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                    
<div class="col-12 text-center tm-submit-container">
    <button type="submit" name="but_upload" class="btn btn-primary tm-btn-submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**insertion Code:-**

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){
 
  $name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
  $target_dir = "upload/";    // create a folder in a directory.
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

  // Select file type
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Valid file extensions
  $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

  // Check extension
  if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){
 
     // Insert record
     $query = "insert into images(images) values('".$name."')";
     mysqli_query($con,$query);
  
     // Upload file
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

  }
 
}
?>
```

**View Image Code:-**

```
<?php
    $sql = "select * from images";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $image = $row['image'];
          $image_src = "upload/".$image; 
          <img src='<?php echo $image_src;  ?>' >;
    }
?>
```

Comment: i donot want to insert into database i want into a folder

Comment: first you should have to insert into database & move into folder , then  view that image..